# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL

Tags: java, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, jdbi

I am trying to connect from my java app running on a Google Cloud Run instance, to a Google Cloud Sql instance that is part of the same Google Cloud project.

When my app tries to open a connection to the db, it throws the following error...

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.ConnectionException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:google:mysql://my-gc-app:my-cloud-sql-instance/mydb'
```

I have enabled all the correct roles for the cloud run service to connect to the cloud sql instance.

The java code that is establishing the DataSource is as follows...

```
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:google:mysql://my-gc-app:my-cloud-sql-instance/mydb");
    dataSource.setUsername(mySqlUser);
    dataSource.setPassword(mySqlusersPassword);
    dataSource.setMinIdle(5);
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
    dataSource.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(100);
    Database.instantiate(dataSource);
```

Comment: You should set the `driverClassName` property of the data source.

Comment: Set it to what?

Comment: The right driver for the `jdbc:google:mysql:...` JDBC url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a line that specifies which DB type should be used.
For example if you're going to connect to Mysql server.

```
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

If it leads to a driver not found error or sth like that, try adding the library with the keyword `mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.12`